# set the table cell width in iText java pdf

Tags: java, itext

I am using the opensource http://itextpdf.com/ , to create some pdf .

I could create a table , but width of all column are same , I need to change the width of the particular  column  .

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
Phrase tablePhrse = new Phrase("Sl n0", normalFontBold);
    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(tablePhrse);
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);
```

I could not find any method to set the width of the column , pls suggest some way to do achieve this ..

Comment: You can make use of `column.setPreferredWidth(100);`

Comment: I could not find the .setPreferredWidth(100) method under PdfTable or PdfCell ..

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I think you can make use of `table.setTotalWidth(); ` and `table.setWidths(); `

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can make use of setWidths() method.

```
table.setWidths(new int[]{200,50});
```

[public void setWidths(int[] relativeWidths)](http://www.docjar.org/docs/api/com/lowagie/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html#setWidths%28float%29)

Comment: The number of itens in array must be the same the number of columns defined in PdfPTable constructor

Comment: @dellasavia: Thanks for pointing that out, but this was an example.

Comment: What if col is dynamic and i want to set the width for the first only

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
float[] columnWidths = new float[]{10f, 20f, 30f, 10f};
table.setWidths(columnWidths);
```

Comment: What do you consider the advantage of your code over that in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected one if `table.setWidths(new int[]{200,50});` does not work.

```
innertable.setWidthPercentage(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set table total width

```
// Set Column Number
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

// Set Table Total Width
table.setTotalWidth(500);

// Set Each Column Width - Make Sure Array is the same number specified in constructor
table.setWidths(new int[]{50, 450});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float[] columnWidths = {1, 5, 5};

// columnWidths = {column1, column2, column3...}

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.